# Execute "LaunchUriAsync" from a click of a HoloLens UI Button

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm trying to do a "LaunchUriAsync" and I have trouble trying to get to it to launch from a ButtonPress event. I've tried to edit from the guide at Microsoft Developer "Call Remote Assist from our Hololens" as I do not require the GestureRecognizer for it.

Are there any solutions/workaround for this ?

Here is the portion of the code I'm referencing:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input;

public class CallApp : MonoBehaviour
{
      // Use this for initialization
    async void Start()
    {

    }

    public void CallActive()
    {
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
        string uriToLaunch = @"ms-voip-video:?contactids=2914d36d-34f5-4f86-8196-52f4e53cf384";
        Debug.Log("LaunchUriAsync: " + uriToLaunch);

        System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(uriToLaunch);
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            // Work done on the UI thread
            LaunchURI(uri).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        });
#endif
    }


    public async Task LaunchURI(System.Uri uri)
    {
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
        // Launch the URI
        try
        {
            var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

            if (success)
            {
                Debug.Log("URI launched");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("URI launch failed");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log(ex.Message);
        }
#endif
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you followed the steps in this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/10/05/call-remote-assist-from-your-hololens-app/), i.e. used the platform dependent compilation directive?

Comment: Yes, but I'm currently stuck on how to run "LaunchUriAsync" method through a ButtonPress event. I've added in '#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT' and I'm unsure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Could you please edit the question and include the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean is that you don't know how to call a function with the button? If so, please select the button in your hierarchy, there should be a "Button" component on the inspector. Add a new entry (+ symbol) in the "On Click()"-List. Now you have to drag the GameObject with the attached script into the new entry field (no-object), after that you will be able to select a function which will be called everytime you clicking the button.

If you need a Step-by-step guide, you can refer to this link :https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/149007/running-a-c-function-in-unity-with-a-button-press

If you are using PressableButton from MRTKv2, you can drag the GameObject and select a function in the location shown below [image]

See the official documentation for more information: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Button.html